# Modificar registros a través de la relación con Eloquent HasOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Tengo una tabla facturas y una tabla imágenes relacionadas de la siguiente forma factura hasOne imagen. Entonces me gustaría que por medio de esta relación al momento de crear una nueva factura poder modificar un registro imagen que ya esta guardado en la base de datos. Cambiando el campo factura_id por el ID de la factura creada.

Que debo hacer para que funcione?

```
 public function store(SaveFacturaRequest $request)
```

{

```
    $cliente_id = request('cliente_id');
    $rnc_cedula = request('rnc_cedula');
    $bienes = request('bienes');
    $ncf = request('ncf');
    $ncf_modificado = request('ncf_modificado');
    $date_comp = request('date_comp');
    $date_pago = request('date_pago');
    $tipo_bien = request('tipo_bien');
    $monto_servicios = request('monto_servicios');
    $monto_bienes = request('monto_bienes');
    $itebis_fact = request('itebis_fact');
    $itebis_retenido = request('itebis_retenido');
    $itebis_sujeto = request('itebis_sujeto');
    $itebis_costo = request('itebis_costo');
    $tipo_retencion = request('tipo_retencion');
    $monto_ret = request('monto_ret');
    $isr = request('isr');
    $impuesto_selec = request('impuesto_selec');
    $otras_tasas = request('otras_tasas');
    $propina = request('propina');
    $forma_pago = request('forma_pago');
    $operador = auth()->user()->name;

Factura::create([
    'cliente_id'=> $cliente_id,
    'rnc_cedula'=> $rnc_cedula,
    'bienes'=> $bienes,
    'ncf'=> $ncf,
    'ncf_modificado'=> $ncf_modificado,
    'date_comp'=> $date_comp,
    'date_pago'=> $date_pago,
    'tipo_bien'=> $tipo_bien,
    'monto_servicios'=> $monto_servicios,
    'monto_bienes'=> $monto_bienes,
    'itebis_fact'=> $itebis_fact,
    'itebis_retenido'=> $itebis_retenido,
    'itebis_sujeto'=> $itebis_sujeto,
    'itebis_costo'=> $itebis_costo,
    'tipo_retencion'=> $tipo_retencion,
    'monto_ret'=> $monto_ret,
    'isr'=> $isr,
    'impuesto_selec'=> $impuesto_selec,
    'otras_tasas'=> $otras_tasas,
    'propina'=> $propina,
    'forma_pago'=> $forma_pago,
    'operador'=> $operador,
]);





return redirect()->route('home.index');
```

}

Este es modelo de la factura:

```
 //Una factura tiene una sola imagen
public function imagen(){
    return $this->hasOne(Imagen::class);
}



//Cada imagen pertenece a un unico usuario
public function cliente(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
}
```

Comment: Estas en el sitio en español amigo, corrige tu pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, evita realizar varias veces la misma pregunta, realiza una pregunta en base a [ask], agregando lo que intentaste o investigaste. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio,saludos.